# Laravel compare three columns in different tables returns 0 items

Tags: database, laravel

Im new at Laravel and i want to compare three columns of two different tables with as data numbers with dot(4.3, 6.00, 30.40). I have this logic but it returns 0 (no items). Any idea why?

```php
public function index()
{        
    $tips = DB::table('tips')->where('status','1')->get();

    foreach($tips as $tip){
        $eventHome[] = $tip->home;
        $eventDraw[] = $tip->draw;
        $eventAway[] = $tip->away;
    }

    $events = DB::table('apidata')
        ->where('oddsHome','=', $eventHome)
        ->where('oddsDraw','=', $eventDraw)
        ->where('oddsAway','=', $eventAway)
        ->get();   

    dd($events);
}
```

Im using the code above to replace this code in my blade:

```
@foreach($events as $event)

    @foreach ($tips as $tip)

    @if($event->eventHome == $tip->home
    and $event->eventDraw == $tip->draw
    and $event->eventAway == $tip->away)
@endforeach
@endforeach
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: since this `$eventHome`, `$eventDraw`, `$eventAway` are arrays. you need to use `whereIn()`

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have a 193 rows in my db, and with that three condition must show 30 exactly. With your suggestion still showing 193! I want to do the same as this in blade ```    @if($evento->oddsHome == $tip->home
    and $evento->oddsDraw == $tip->draw
    and $evento->oddsAway == $tip->away)``` but in my controller!

Comment: In this code, `$tip` is a one tip. but in your controller code `DB::table('tips')->where('status','1')->get()` are multiple tips. I thinks that's why. So you need to fetch the exact tip from the database I guess

Comment: So whats the best way to do it

Comment: Please check my update

Comment: Post your complete foreach in blade file here. that would be helpfull.

Comment: In my opinion the most important part of my blade are the foreach that i posted three comments above this. The rest are td th from tables.

Comment: The important part is what's inside the if body. Because there is the point we can figure out what you really want to do, instead of what you have asked. Most of the people in stack overflow questions they are asking the wrong question. And there example code misguide the people who trying to answer. Sometimes the answers are a single line of code rather that the posted questions code. So explain what you want to achieve in English rather than code (but with the code snipped you have tried, ofcource) .

Answer (score 0):

use `php artisan tinker` to test each query in your code.

in tinker write `DB::table('tips')->where('status','1')->get();` if the result is not null so make next query with constant (custom) values from previous:

```
DB::table('apidata')
    ->where('oddsHome','=', 4.3)
    ->where('oddsDraw','=', 6.00)
    ->where('oddsAway','=', 30.40)
    ->get();
```

if the result still is null surely there is no data with exact numbers. and if is not null, you may have a problem in your model. for example home or draw is not defined.

for more help you must share your models and some of data in db.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have this code working on my blade: @foreach($eventos as $evento)

    @foreach ($tips as $tip)

    @if($evento->oddsHome == $tip->home
    and $evento->oddsDraw == $tip->draw
    and $evento->oddsAway == $tip->away) enforeach enforeach And it works but i want this in my controller

Comment: yes you can do while loop in controller and send its variable throw return (compact(...)) and set js variable like var eventos = $eventos. the you can use my js function.

Comment: As I said im newbie at this. Can you share with us the entire working code? Thanks so much

Comment: surely , create new repository in gitlab.com and add your files to that. then add me (hmdshariati@aol.om) as member to help you.